# SSIS check if record was deleted

Tags: ssis, detect, consolidation

I am facing a situation where I have built SSIS package for consolidating a table from multiple databases but sometimes DBA manually deletes records from source tables. Is there any way to detect on consolidated table if a record was deleted? I know that I can truncate consolidated table each time before the package runs but I wonder if there's another way?

Comment: hi, can you give more details? You read DB1, DB2 and DB3 and insert data on your consolidating table, right? Whats the problem with the deletion on the source DBs? does it break something? or is it just the missing record?

Comment: Does your consolidated table have a mechanism to uniquely tie a row back to a source system?

Comment: @Diego: If a record from DB1 is deleted then it still exists in consolidated table.

Comment: @billinkc: I can tie a row (logically) from consolidated db to source db by originalID and sourceID.

Comment: but whats the issue? you want to delete from the destination table then?

Answer (score 1):

I demonstrate one way to manage deleting data in the destination that has been deleted in the source in the [Stairway to Integration Services series](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/) at SQL Server Central.

Hope this helps,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

I thought of several solutions, but I realize now the big issue is that you don’t have an unified data source, so a record may not exist in A but exist in B, thus you can’t delete it.

So my suggestion is, after you inserted, run a select distinct(id) from all sources and put them together on a structure (table, temp table, view, UNION, whatever..) and run a Merge from this source into destination on the IDs with only a WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN DELETE.